# Background Setup for My Title Page

Tags: titles, backgrounds, tikz-pic

I am having trouble setting up the background for my title page using tikz. I adopted this background style from Benmiloud Mohammed at https://latexdraw.com/. I also adopted the contents of the title page `\titleTMB` from pages 25, 59-60 of *Some Examples of
Title Pages* by Peter Wilson available at https://mirror.ufs.ac.za/ctan/info/latex-samples/TitlePages/titlepages.pdf. Now, using the `background` package, I failed to create the background for my title page indicated in the following picture (source: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tikz-examples/LatexGraphics/master/CoverPageStar.tex):
[image: Desired Background]
Below is my MWE:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[12pt,openany,twoside]{book}
\raggedbottom

\usepackage{background}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
 
\usepackage{fontspec}% this package is important in my project

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ shapes.geometric }
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newlength{\drop}
\begin{document} 

    \begin{titlepage}
        
        \backgroundsetup{
            scale=1,
            angle=0,
            opacity=1,
            contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
                    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Background %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                    \fill[Dandelion] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
                    
                    
                    \foreach \i in {100,95,...,5}{
                        \node[fill=Dandelion!\i,draw=none,star, minimum size=\i cm,thick] at (current page.east){}; }
            \end{tikzpicture}}
        }
        
        \drop=0.1\textheight
        \centering
        \vspace*{\baselineskip}
        \rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt}
        \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\\[\baselineskip]
        {\LARGE CONUNDRUMS\\ AND \\[0.3\baselineskip] PUZZLES}\\[0.2\baselineskip]
        \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt}
        \rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\\[\baselineskip]
        \scshape
        Selected and Expanded Papers from the Organisation Working Conference on \\
        Enigmas \\
        Location, date from--to\par
        \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
        Edited by \\[\baselineskip]
        {\Large FIRST EDITOR \\ SECOND EDITOR \\ THIRD EDITOR\par}
        {\itshape Organisation \\ Address\par}
        \vfill
        {\scshape year} \\
        {\large THE PUBLISHER}\par
        
    \end{titlepage}
    
    \backgroundsetup{contents={}}
    
    \chapter{Results}
    \section{Equations and Matrices}
    \subsection{Equations}
    AMS package is loaded to typeset Higher Mathematics equations. A single equation can be on one line, several lines (no alignment) and several lines (with alignment). Also equation groups can be without alignment, with simple alignment and or multiple alignment. Equations can also be in cases.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get errors as you have empty lines in the code for the background contents.

I wouldn't use the background package for this, it uses internally a tikz picture too, and nesting tikz pictures is difficult. Also using the `current page` nodes requires always two compilations. You can do the same with the shipout/background hook.

Don't use T1 encoding with lualatex/xelatex. That is the wrong font encoding for the unicode engines.

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany,twoside]{book}
\raggedbottom

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{fontspec}% this package is important in my project

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ shapes.geometric }
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\newlength{\drop}
\begin{document}
\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}
{\put(0,-\paperheight)
  {%
   \begin{tikzpicture}   
   \fill[use as bounding box,Dandelion] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
   \foreach \i in {100,95,...,5}{
     \node[fill=Dandelion!\i,draw=none,star, minimum size=\i cm,thick] at (0.5\paperwidth,0){}; }
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
}

    \begin{titlepage}

        \drop=0.1\textheight
        \centering
        \vspace*{\baselineskip}
        \rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt}
        \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\\[\baselineskip]
        {\LARGE CONUNDRUMS\\ AND \\[0.3\baselineskip] PUZZLES}\\[0.2\baselineskip]
        \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt}
        \rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\\[\baselineskip]
        \scshape
        Selected and Expanded Papers from the Organisation Working Conference on \\
        Enigmas \\
        Location, date from--to\par
        \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
        Edited by \\[\baselineskip]
        {\Large FIRST EDITOR \\ SECOND EDITOR \\ THIRD EDITOR\par}
        {\itshape Organisation \\ Address\par}
        \vfill
        {\scshape year} \\
        {\large THE PUBLISHER}\par

    \end{titlepage}

 

    \chapter{Results}
    \section{Equations and Matrices}
    \subsection{Equations}
    AMS package is loaded to typeset Higher Mathematics equations. A single equation can be on one line, several lines (no alignment) and several lines (with alignment). Also equation groups can be without alignment, with simple alignment and or multiple alignment. Equations can also be in cases.
\end{document}
```

[image]